# How to find out when a mounted file system or device was mounted?

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, devices

Not every file system or device is mounted during boot time. On servers it sometimes happens that a server log might already being rotated.

How to find out when a mounted file system or device was mounted?

---

Note:  Answers should be general, rather than specific to a particular file system.  But specific file system answers would be better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

`tune2fs -l devname` will give you the last mount date for local ext? partitions.

Comment: I would be ideal if the tool could also do this for cifs mounts etc