# Sort mount points by mount time

Tags: linux, mount, sort

With no command line arguments `mount` displays all mounted file systems, e.g.:

```
/dev/sdy8 on /bar type ext4 (rw,relatime,lazytime,data=ordered)
/dev/sdx6 on /baz type ext4 (rw,relatime,lazytime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/sdz9 on /foo type ext4 (rw,relatime,lazytime,data=ordered)
{ etc... }
```

How can these be sorted by *time*, specifically the respective times each file system was first *mount*ed?

Because `sort` can take care of the actual numerical *sorting*, the question's answer depends on:  [How to find out when a mounted file system or device was mounted?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253392/how-to-find-out-the-time-since-something-was-mounted)

Comment: It seems to me the output is already in that order.

Comment: True, (but irrelevant).  The `mount` listing that prompted this was a bunch of leftover *cgroup* garbage that `grub-probe` was hanging on.  Since fixed -- but along the way the above question came up.  (I've just mixed up the order of the above example.)

Comment: I mean in what circumstance would the order not be by mount time? It seems to me entries are always appended to that list upon mount (on Linux at least). That's the case when `mount` takes the info from /etc/mtab, but that seems to also be the case for /proc/self/mounts and /proc/self/mountinfo. In any case, I don't think the mount time is recorded. You'd need to  audit the mount() system calls.

Comment: How is it irrelevant? If you're after the mount time, then make that your question's focus; don't create an artificial sorting problem.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, the circumstance are obscure, but somehow something to do with a failing `grub` upgrade led to [this _mount_ output](http://pastebin.com/ZTYdeCst).

Comment: @StephenKitt, perhaps you're right about focus, and there being a separable question, but it's no artificial sorting problem. Getting only the date would be the least convenient answer.

Comment: Given your pastebin, yes, it's not artificial; but that's not apparent in your question. I found it particularly odd that you edited the `mount` output to make it unsorted without explaining why! If you explicitly said "I noticed strange `mount` output" and explained the circumstances, the question would read quite differently.

Comment: @StephenKitt, sorry, my fault -- in the _Edit Summary_ I'd meant to write something like "Abstracted & randomized example".  Note the example now has _foo_, _bar_, _baz_ mountpoints.

Comment: The pastebin you link to is `/etc/mtab`, which looks like it contains the current mounts in chronological order, with some cruft left behind from a previous boot before them. What makes you think that, apart from the cruft, the order is not mount time order?

Comment: I'm not sure there's anything wrong at all with the pastebin contents, not even cruft from a previous boot. The filesystems listed before / were probably mounted from the initramfs, and / was pivoted...

Comment: @Gilles, without first knowing the mount times, are we certain what the mount time order is?

Comment: @StephenKitt, had to look up that usage of "_pivoted_", which probably stems from [`man 2 pivot_root`](http://phpunixman.sourceforge.net/index.php/man/pivot_root/2).  Its _BUGS_ section cautions: _"Some of the more obscure uses of pivot_root() may quickly lead to insanity."_

Comment: So far I gather that it might be best to split this into three questions:  1) Sorting mount points by mount time, (current OP, possibly unnecessary & impossible)   2) Find mount point mount time via some _in advance_ sideways method (debugging, auditing, emulation, et al).   3) Best ways to clean up a crufty `/etc/mtab`.